# Dynamically render and remove HTML knockoutjs

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js

So I'm having an odd issue. I am iterating with a ko foreach:,  I have 2 "if" statements.

```
ifnot: row.disabled
 //this html
if: row.disabled
 //that html
```

all rows start disabled on page load. my page is formatted something like this

```
**Enabled**

//empty

**Disabled**

thing1      

thing 2

thing 3
```

this is fine. It works as expected... Except for one little thing. the ifNot has a div that I need for another plugin. This is causing an unexpected side-effect. "Html to display when row is enabled" is still there, just missing some child elements.

```
 <!--ko foreach blah in thing-->
 <div class="i need this to be here">
 <!--ko ifnot: row.disabled-->
    html to display when row is enabled
 <!--/ko-->
 </div>
 <!--/ko-->
```

The side-effect is that when I getElementById, then querySelectorAll(html to display...) it's getting all rows, when, for this use case, the rows can't be there if they are disabled.

I need to dynamically render, or remove this html from my page when the state of the row changes. I'm trying something like this, and I've seen the template: binding, but I can't figure out how to use it.

Please, if you can laymans the template binding for a novice, or figure out how to bind what I have, or modify what I have below to add and remove html from the dom dynamically, that'd be wonderful.

P.S.No jQuery

```
self.template = ko.observable();

    self.toggleTemplate = function (row) {
        var template = ko.observable();
        if (!row.disabled) {
            self.template(enabledRowTemplate);
        }
        else {
            self.template(null);
        }
    };
```

Comment: can you show an actual example of the html you actually need to see in each case?

Comment: No. 

And really it shouldn't matter what the html is. I need it turned on and off. 
for the sake of argument us this
<div>
<p data-bind="text: 'Hello, ' + this.thing + ' is now active'> </p>
</div>

Comment: I'm asking so I know which blocks should show up for each case, what should always be visible and where, etc, so I can figure out an appropriate template to solve this.

Comment: not so much the content, but more the actual structure of what you're expecting. the samples you showed weren't consistent, so I'm having a hard time figuring out what behavior you need

Comment: nothing should always be visible, but there is a wrapper div around the if, like i mentioned before. 

<div class="i need this to be here"> is equivalent to, that has to be there.
<div class="draggable">

Comment: The way you have it set up, there's a div always visible for each row (I need this to be here), then another conditional div based on the row.disabled flag

Comment: Please, try to explain in a better way what your problem is. Even reading the comments is nearly impossible to understand it. Show only the important code, what you expect to get, and what you get. That would makes it much easier to understand.

Answer (score 1):

Simple example of the template binding, hope this helps

```html
<!--ko foreach blah in thing-->
<div class="i need this to be here">
    <!-- ko template: template --><!-- /ko -->
 </div>
<!--/ko-->

<script type="text/html" id="enabledRowTemplate">
  html to display when row is enabled
</script>
<script type="text/html" id="disabledRowTemplate">
  html to display when row is disabled
</script>
```

and in JS

```
self.template = ko.computedObservable(function(){
   return self.enabled ? 'enabledRowTemplate' : 'disabledRowTemplate' // or {name: templateName, data: templateData} instead of template name string 
});
```